# Using sections in ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am having a bootstrap problem I hope one of you might have a solution to.

I have placed all my JavaScript references in the bottom of my masterpage. This usually works fine, but now I have a ASCX control which needs to add some JavaScript too the footer (initialization of a module). The reason why I can't initialize the module from the master page is because I need some properties from my codebehind file.

In ASP.NET MVC I would have used sections to inject data from a usercontrol to a section in the masterpage, but is this even possible in ASP.NET Webforms 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that concept of sections in not available in WebForms.

One way to do what you've described is to use the `<%= %>` syntax and send the values of server properties to the client (HTML output). In your ASCX control you can have the following markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clientProperty = <%= MyServerProperty %>; 
</script>
```

ASP.NET WebForms will substitute the value of MyServerProperty above when it renders the page, and then you can access clientProperty as a global variable from the script in the masterpage.

Another approach is to use a [Hidden field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and set its value on the server. It will be rendered as an `<input type="hidden">`, whose value you can then get from any script by ID.

A third option is to load the actual client script only from the ASCX control (when it makes sense), rather than put it in the masterpage (when it will be loaded  everywhere in the site).

Answer (score 1):

You could add something like this to the bottom of your master page:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="javascriptSection" />
```

Then in your page's code behind or in a `<% %>` tag:

```
var scriptTag = new HtmlGenericControl("script");

scriptTag.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript";

scriptTag.InnerHtml = @"function () { ... }";

var javascriptSection = this.Page.Master.FindControl("javascriptSection");

if (javascriptSection != null)
    javascriptSection.Controls.Add(scriptTag);
```